# Laravel5.5 windows 関数の呼び出し方があっているのかわかりません

Tags: php, laravel-5

Laravel5で、ボタンでCreateとLikesの処理を分けたいんですが、うまく実行できません。

ボタンの処理は別のPHPファイルに書いてます。

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name = "create">質問投稿</button>
```

`create_qa`と`Update_likes_whenbuttonClick`は単体であれば実行ができているのは分かっているのですが、振り分けるための`button_Click`関数に入れた途端動かなくなります。（ページが真っ白になり、それぞれの関数に記述したDBの処理そのものはできています
`return`で、振り分けそのものができていることは確認しました（IDを表示することができたので、問題がないかと思っています）。

何か間違っていそうか分かる人教えていただけると助かります。他に情報が必要な場合は書き足しますので、よろしくお願いします。

Controllerの中身は以下の通りです。

```
public function button_click(Request $request,$session_id){ 
    if(isset($_POST["create"])){ 
        $this->create_qa($request,$session_id); 
    } 
    else if(isset($_POST["likes"])){ 
        //return $session_id; これはできてる 
        $this->update_likes_whenbuttonClick($request,$session_id); 
    } 
}

public function create_qa(Request $request,$session_id) {
    ～
}

public function update_likes_whenbuttonClick(Request $request, $qatable_id){
    ～
}
```

Comment: 解決しました、分岐内にreturn viewを書いていなかったのが原因の様でした・・・

Comment: 自己解決した場合はぜひ「回答」として投稿してもらうと、他のユーザの助けになるかもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

cubickさんからご指摘いただいたので回答として残しておきます。

```
public function button_click(Request $request,$session_id){ 
    if(isset($_POST["create"])){ 
        $this->create_qa($request,$session_id); 
    } 
    else if(isset($_POST["likes"])){ 
        //return $session_id; これはできてる 
        $this->update_likes_whenbuttonClick($request,$session_id); 
    } 
}

public function create_qa(Request $request,$session_id) {
    ～

         return view('qaupdate');
}

public function update_likes_whenbuttonClick(Request $request, $qatable_id){
    ～
}
```

と、呼び出したいメソッドの中にreturn viewが書かれている状態になっていたreturn viewを、ボタン振り分けのメソッド内の方に記述

```
public function button_click(Request $request,$session_id){ 
    if(isset($_POST["create"])){ 
        $this->create_qa($request,$session_id); 
         return view('qaupdate');
    } 
    else if(isset($_POST["likes"])){ 
        //return $session_id; これはできてる 
        $this->update_likes_whenbuttonClick($request,$session_id); 
         return view('likeupdate');
    } 
}

public function create_qa(Request $request,$session_id) {
    ～

}

public function update_likes_whenbuttonClick(Request $request, $qatable_id){
    ～
}
```

これで、うまくページが表示されるようになりました